# MySQL Workbench Crash on Execute (Mac)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm currently using MySQL version 8.0.28 and MySQL Workbench 8.0.29 on Macbook Pro 2017. When on the most recent version of MySQL Workbench (8.0.31), Workbench started crashing whenever I went to generate a new model using the Import feature to create a diagram of an existing schema.

To simplify the problem, I tried creating a test database with a single varchar column and seeing if I could run a 'show tables' query. Even that made Workbench close out immediately.

At this point, I've also tried downloading a slightly older version of Workbench, quitting, restarting my computer, etc., and nothing is working. I probably need to provide more detail but am quite new to working with databases so just let me know if there's anything else that I should mention.

Comment: So sorry, I'm on Mac. Just edited my post. I agree, though, it doesn't seem to be MySQL as I can access and query my database via the terminal.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?
My MySQL is also terminating everytime i execute command.

Comment: I ended up just switching to dBeaver...